# Android how to get Integer value from hashmap

Tags: java, android

```
HashMap<String,Integer>alert=( HashMap<String,Integer>) documentSnapshot.get("alert");
                        Log.e("alert",String.valueOf(alert));
                        Integer days=alert.get("days").intValue();
                        Integer hours=alert.get("hours").intValue();
                        Integer minutes=alert.get("minutes").intValue();
```

// here is my logcat

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at FirstFlowFragments.BookAppointmentFragment$2.onComplete(BookAppointmentFragment.java:234)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:23)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
```

I am fetching hashmap values from firebase database the value is coming.The values inside the hashmap is integer when i try to get those values its giving exception like java.Long cannot cast to integer.

Comment: Please give more code for understanding your problem

Comment: This is the actual  code

Comment: all the values inside the hashmap is stored in integer.i want to get those values

Comment: for fetching the value from hash map is simple 
Like  Integer days=Integer.parseInt(alert.get("days"));

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get, and indicate which line the exception is thrown. You should neither need to cast, nor invoke `intValue()` if the values are already `Integer`. The problem is probably the cast in your first line.

Comment: if you are reading data from firebase it is in object format so you need to parse to the corresponding data types

Comment: What is the integer value of days in your database.

Comment: Integer day=Integer.parseInt(alert.get("days")); when i try to parse like this it saying  (java.lang.String) integer cannot be applied to int

Comment: @SavinSharma the value is 0 right now may be in future it will change like 2 or 3

Comment: Your `alert` is probably a `Map<String,Long>` - try to cange your cast and see if that helps. If it doesn't help, inspect the runtime type with a debugger (or print out the result of calling `.getClass()` on it).

Comment: k i will try.but if the hashmap is Map<String,Long> i cannot able to get hashmap values.i am already getting the values of  hashmap

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the actual types of the values of `dataSnapshot.getValue()` are, and cast it to the correct type of Map to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the values as long, and then cast it to Integer

```
Integer days= Math.toIntExact(alert.get("days").longValue());
Integer hours= Math.toIntExact(alert.get("hours").longValue());
Integer minutes= Math.toIntExact(alert.get("minutes").longValue());
```

Comment: this code is applicable for above the sdk version 24

Comment: Yes, you can use an standard cast instead: 
Integer days = (int)alert.get("days").longValue();

Answer (score 0):

If your database contains only the integer value not float or double then you can directly get the `Integer` value from the key of your `HashMap`. No need to add `.intValue()`.

```
Integer days=alert.get("days");
Integer hours=alert.get("hours");
Integer minutes=alert.get("minutes");
```

If the value is `float` in your database then you can use the following code.

```
if(alert.get("days")!=null) {
   int days = Math.round(alert.get("days"));
}
```